# Can neuro-fuzzy systems be used for supervised learning tasks with tabular data?

Tags: neural-networks, classification, applications, regression

Is it possible to use neuro-fuzzy systems for problems where ANNs are currently being used, for instance, when you have tabular data for regression or classification tasks? What kind of advantage can give me neuro-fuzzy systems over using an ANN for the mentioned tasks?

Comment: You can insert expert knowledge in the form of linguistic rules; if that's applicable for your tasks, then they will quite probably help; though I don't know of any (review) paper comparing these two approaches quantitatively.